# How to fail the build based on $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING environment variable in aws codebuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, devops, aws-codebuild

I am trying to set the variable $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING in aws codebuild to 0 based on a condition in post build to fail the build action, but it is not failing. (though the value is assigned as expected during post build)

Here is the post build section

```
var=$(<test_result.txt) |  [ "$var" == "failed" ] && CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING=1 || CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING=0
echo "The value is ...."
echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it is not failing (though the value is assigned as expected during post build)

A non-zero value of `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` is **not going to fail** the build. A non-zero exit code will do this. The `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` is used when you want to do something in post_build, based on whether the build stage failed or not.

If you just want to fail the build you can use `exit 255` or any non-zero value in post_build when `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` is non-zero.

For example, you could add in the post_build

```
[[ $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING != 0 ]] && exit 255 || echo "post_build execution continues"
```

Answer (score 1):

The below mentioned logic doesn't seem to be right. According to the [AWS article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING is 1 when the build succeeds, otherwise it is failed. So the right check should be,

```
[[ $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING == 0 ]] && exit 255 || echo "post_build execution continues"
```